# How to fix 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' in Android .aar project

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, aar

I have an android `.aar` library built and I am trying to integrate it with one of the projects. When the app tries to open the initial screen of the `.aar` library where I have API call using retrofit. I am getting the below exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution
>   of:Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;

I have not obfuscated or enabled pro-guard in my `.aar` project.

Below are my `.aar` Gradle dependencies

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: do you enabled instant-run? and running your app in below android M?

Comment: How are you referencing the aar in the project that's using it?

Comment: @Mark implementation project(path: ':LibraryName') this how i am referencing the aar

Comment: @RajasekaranM I have disabled instant-run and running the app in android M

Comment: still issue exists?

Comment: Ya, I tried changing implementation to api. but I have the same issue.

Comment: @NiranjanS have you got the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you got solution i am facing same issue

Answer (score 15):

OK, this is a common issue. There are several ways to use an android library(aar) in other projects. For example:

1. By importing this aar as a module into your sample project by using
   `implementation project(':mylibrary')`.
2. By uploading your aar to a maven repository(artifactory, maven local, Jitpack, etc)

**Pay attention to this:**

1. If you are using number 1 above, so you will also have to
       add(retrofit, okhttp3, etc) to your sample project with the same
       version, because the aar by default doesn't include child
       dependencies. That's why you are getting that exception
       "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
       Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder'".
2. If you are using number 2 above, so you will have to make sure that your pom.xml file includes your child dependencies, because the server needs to download and have them available in your sample project.

**What do I recommend?**

I recommend developers to use `MavenLocal()`, it replicates a real scenario before publishing your aar to a public repository like Jitpack or whatever you want.

**How can I do it?**

1. **Inside build.gradle of your library module**:

`apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                setGroupId 'YOUR_GROUP_ID'
                //You can either define these here or get them from project conf elsewhere
                setArtifactId 'YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID'
                version android.defaultConfig.versionName
                artifact bundleReleaseAar //aar artifact you want to publish

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run `assemble` and `publishToMavenLocal` gradle tasks. And you'll see something like this:
[image]

2. **In your Sample Project**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
    }
}
```

`implementation '${YOUR_GROUP_ID}:${YOUR_ARTIFACT_ID}:${YOUR_VERSION}'`

Comment: If you haven't specified signing info, you'll get a `no configured signatory` error. Follow here to add signatory credentials:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you've built your .aar, and published it to a maven repository (artifactory, nexus, what have you) - e.g., "implementation 'com.mycompany:library:1.0@aar'".  Any child dependencies need to be included in the pom.xml delivered by the server to have them available in your application.

Since you've used the "implementation" keyword, those dependencies are considered private to the .aar, and will not be listed in the pom.xml. So they will not be available in your aar, and not automatically imported into the project by gradle.

If you change to the api keyword to "api" instead of implementation, those dependencies become public, and should be listed in the generated pom.xml, and thus should be automatically imported into the project.

This is actually also true also with aar's inside modules, rather than referenced via external systems (e.g. implementation project(':mylibrary') ). If you need the dependencies of mylibrary to run the project, they need to be api.

For reference, you may want to take a look at the [Android Studio Dependency Configurations Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations).

If, however, you're manually including the arr via a files statement (e.g., implementation files('libs/my.aar')), then you don't get automatic dependency management, and you're going to have to add the libraries needed by your aar to the main project manually as well via copy and paste between the build.gradle files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help @Mark. I have not published my .aar to the maven repository. It's a local module which I tried to import the library using api like this 'api project(':MyLibrary')' but didn't work.

Comment: No, within the MyLibrary module, you need to change your dependencies from implementation to API, eg, for okhttp, retrofit, etc. Then they will be "public", and available to your parent project.

Comment: Thanks, Mark I have changed my library module dependencies from module to api and re-imported the library in the project, but I have the same issue **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder'**

Comment: If you've got "api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'" and you're still getting this message... have you tried turning off proguard (could be you're missing proguard rules and the class is getting stripped).

Comment: Ya, I have tried turning off the proguard and even tried adding proguard rules, but still, I have the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `fat-aar` to solve this https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix was to change

```
compileOnly files('libs/mylibrary.aar')
```

in gradle to

```
implementation files('libs/mylibrary.aar')
```

and the error was gone.